# Weird result whe nusing OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews

Tags: hlsl, deferred-rendering, rendertargets

My render pass consist in four passes.

3 first have 2 rendertargets and two unordered access view.

RTV0 = RG88 //store normal.xy

RTV1 = R32 //store depth

UAV0 = R32UINT //store color1

UAV1 = R32UINT//store color2

4th has one RTV and one UAV.

RTV0 = RG88//store normal.xy

UAV0 = R32UINT//store color1

I’m setting viewport and scissor rect as the screen size.
So I set OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews(2, RTVs, DSV, 2, 2, UAVs, NULL) for the 3 first and OMSetRenderTargetsAndUnorderedAccessViews(1, RTVs, DSV, 1, 1, UAVs, NULL) for the last.

In my shader

```
    RWTexture2D<uint> UAVDiffuse0  : register( u2 );
    RWTexture2D<uint> UAVDiffuse1  : register( u3 );
    
    struct PS_INPUT
    {
        float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
        float3 Norm : NORMAL;
        float4 Col : COLOR0;
        float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
        float3 Tan : TANGENT;
        float3 BiN : BINORMAL;
    };
    
    struct PS_DEFERRED
    {
        float2 NormalSSR : SV_TARGET0;
        float Depth : SV_TARGET1;
    };
    
    Float4 psdeferred (PS_INPUT Input)
    {
    PS_DEFERRED Output;
    Some code to calculate Data and N from Input
    //SM_SCREENX and Y are the screen sizes
        UAVDiffuse0[Input.Tex*float2(SM_SCREENX,SM_SCREENY)] = Data;
        UAVDiffuse1[Input.Tex*float2(SM_SCREENX,SM_SCREENY)] = Data&0xFFFF7FFF;
        Output.NormalSSR = mad(N.xy,0.5,0.5);
        Output.Depth = Input.Pos.z+0.00003f;
    }
    
    struct PS_DEFERRED2 
    {
        float2 NormalSSR : SV_TARGET0;
    };
    Float4 psdeferred2 (PS_INPUT Input)
    {
    PS_DEFERRED2 Output;
    Some code to calculate Data and N from Input
        UAVDiffuse0[Input.Tex*float2(SM_SCREENX,SM_SCREENY)] = Data;
        Output.NormalSSR = mad(N.xy,0.5,0.5);
    }
```

Things work fine for the RTVs but are weird for UAVs as shown in the picture. In my previous code I was using RTV only and everything was working fine so I’m sure that the Data and N calculations are correct.
I’m surely missing something. I have no debug errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fill stupid...
The answer was [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839957/writing-on-a-uav-in-pixel-shader) already. We need to use the SV_POSITION xy as UAV coordinates for writing the right pixel.